# Flexibility of Symfony annotations

Tags: annotations, symfony

I use annotations for stand Symfony routes such as...

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
```

...quite happily, however I would have liked/expected some flexibility with the comments to be able to make each new route more visually identifiable - for example:

```
/********************************************************************
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 ********************************************************************/
```

However, when I try this, I get an error:

> No route found for "GET /"

Is there a way the `*`s (or `#`s can be extended such as above? (or is there a strong reason for not being able to do this?)

Comment: The `/**` and `*/` with their respective whitespace characters are what the [comment block parser](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/glossary.html#term-8) is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you cannot use `/************` but I think one of these would be good enough for your purpose. I think 1st one looks better, at least to me!

```
/**
 * ***********************************
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @Route("")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 *
 * @throws Exception
 * ***********************************
 */

/** ***********************************
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @Route("")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 *
 * @throws Exception
 * ***********************************/

/** *******************************
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @Route("")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 *
 * @throws Exception
 ** ******************************/
```